# HTTP response splitting attack prevention in perl

Tags: perl, http, response

## How to prevent HTTP response splitting attack?

HTTP Response splitting allows an attacker to manipulate the response received by a web browser. is there any way to prevent this kind of attack from perl.

Answer (score 2):

As usual. **Do not trust any data received from user.**
If you need to include some data from user to the headers use uri_escape() or other appropriate mechanism which will escape unsafe data.

Comment: Can you give me one example ?

Comment: First give me example of your application

Answer (score 1):

Don't put unsanitized data into headers (e.g. redirects or cookies).